# java <defunct> still present even after killing all java processes

Tags: java, linux, bash, awk, kill

Executed below command to kill java process on linux system.

`ps -ef | grep java | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'| xargs kill -9`

After this when I checked for running java processes, I could find "[java] " process still running.

How to kill these defunct processes ?

Comment: [Zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process)

Comment: Got the solution : get the PPID by running command `ps -ef | grep defunct` . Then kill the PPID which will in turn kills the PID of zombie processes

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` except as a last resort. A simple `kill` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

Zombie (defunct) processes are dead.  All processes on unix hang around after they die until their parent process requests their return status. Most of the time, that happens instantly so you never see that the process is a zombie.  But if the parent process is hung or stopped, it can't release its dead child processes so they hang around as zombies.

Answer (score 0):

Even though defunct processes are killed with kill -9 command, session handles will remain with terminal window. If we logout and login back that will clear all session handles